# Android layouts - programmatically setting value for a custom layout components

Tags: android, xml, layout, customization

I have defined a simple custom layout that includes a text view and an image view. in my main layout I want to use this layout several times and I want to add value to these text and image views in my code. (now manually, but later by taking data from database)

how can I access to these components in my code?

here is my main layout xml file

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@id/comment_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <!-- these four components have the same structure but different styles and behaviors. -->
    <include
        android:id="@+id/like"
        style="@style/LikeStyle"
        android:layout_width="0dip"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        layout="@layout/comment_actions" />

    <include
        android:id="@+id/dislike"
        style="@style/DislikeStyle"
        android:layout_width="0dip"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        layout="@layout/comment_actions" />

    <include
        android:id="@+id/reply"
        style="@style/ReplyStyle"
        android:layout_width="0dip"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        layout="@layout/comment_actions" />

    <include
        android:id="@+id/share"
        style="@style/ShareStyle"
        android:layout_width="0dip"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        layout="@layout/comment_actions" />
</LinearLayout>
```

and the part in my adapter where I want to set data:

```
public View getView(int position, View view, ViewGroup parent) {
    ViewHolder holder = null;
    if (view == null) {
        LayoutInflater infalInflater = (LayoutInflater)ctx.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        view = infalInflater.inflate(R.layout.comment_item, null);
        holder = new ViewHolder();
        holder.userName = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.user_name);
        holder.userImage = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.user_image);
        holder.commentContent = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.comment_content);
        holder.commentTitle = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.comment_title);

        // these tree below layouts are custom. now when running my app i recieve a class cast exception
        // because r.id.like and other twos are relative layout.
        holder.likes = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.like);
        holder.dislikes = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.dislike);
        holder.replys = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.reply);
        view.setTag(holder);
    }
    else {
        holder = (ViewHolder) view.getTag();
    }
    holder.userName.setText(((Comment) listData.get(position)).getUsername());
    holder.commentContent.setText(((Comment)listData.get(position)).getContent());
    holder.commentTitle.setText(((Comment)listData.get(position)).getTitle());

    // the part where I want to set data for these custom layouts.
    holder.likes.setText(((Comment) listData.get(position)).getLikes());
    holder.dislikes.setText(((Comment) listData.get(position)).getDislikes());
    holder.replys.setText(((Comment) listData.get(position)).getReplys());
    return view;
}
```

Comment: A better approach is to write a custom View class, with its own layout and properties.

Comment: Thanks. I would try that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to cast it to `RelativeLayout`. Go to `comment_actions` layout and check if the `TextView` has an ID set. If not, do so.

Then cast your likes, reply and stuff as `RelativeLayout` and find the `TextView` from there:

```
RelativeLayout rlLikes = (RelativeLayout) view.findViewById(R.id.like);
holder.likes = (TextView) rlLikes.findViewById(R.id.idOfTextViewInsideComment_actions);
```

Comment: Yes. TextView and ImageView both have IDs. Thank you very much for helping me out.

Comment: That worked and now I have values set correctly. But when I run the code I see a single number (likes number) instead of 4 numbers and four 4 images (seems that they are on top of each other) 
Have you any idea what is that for?

Comment: No, not really. I guess this has to do with the Layout inside of `comment_actions`.