# Refrencing a selector drawable from a style results blank imagebutton

Tags: android, xml, styles, imagebutton

I want to have a `ImageButtons` changing the image based on its state. (same as "like" button in nine gag and facebook apps).

I have defined a style for each of them that references a selector as a drawable but when I run the program, images doesn't appear. Can you tell me what's wrong with this approach? (sorry for my bad English)

comment_actions_style in values folder:

```
    <style name="LikeStyle">
        <item name="android:src">@drawable/like</item>
    </style>

    <style name="DislikeStyle">
        <item name="android:src">@drawable/dislike_normal</item>
    </style>

    <style name="ReplyStyle">
        <item name="android:src">@drawable/reply_normal</item>
    </style>

    <style name="ShareStyle">
        <item name="android:src">@drawable/share</item>
    </style>
</resources>
```

and like drawable in drawable folder: (other buttons are the same)

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <item android:drawable="@drawable/like_clicked" android:state_pressed="true"/>
 <!-- pressed -->
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/like_focused" android:state_focused="true"/>
 <!-- focused -->
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/like_normal"/>
 <!-- default -->

</selector>
```

**EDIT:**
I forgot to mention, I have a list view that its items are user comments and comments have buttons described above.

here is my items layout (part of it)

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@id/comment_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    >

    <include
        android:id="@+id/like"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        layout="@layout/comment_actions"
        style="@style/LikeStyle" />
</LinearLayout>
```

and comment_actions layout:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/comment_action"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="5dip">
        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/comment_action_img"
            android:layout_width="40dp"
            android:layout_height="40dp"
            android:background="@android:color/transparent"
            />
        <TextView 
            android:id="@+id/comment_action_num"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@id/comment_action_img"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dip"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

These buttons also inherit from a layout if that's matter.

Comment: how do you use the styles? can you post some code?

Comment: @kevinhoo I have edited the code. In case you need more information please sea [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17699196/android-layouts-programmatically-setting-value-for-a-custom-layout-components) question

Comment: what is comment_actions? could you show it?

Comment: @kevinhoo I have 4 buttons with same layout called comment_actions. It is the last code part. in another xml file I define these 4 buttons and they inherit from comment_actions layout (3rd code part).
I hope I've understood your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here, your are setting style for comment_actions layout, and it is a Relative Layout, which won't be abled to response to your "android:src" attribute.

```
<LinearLayout
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_below="@id/comment_content"
android:orientation="horizontal"
>

<include
    android:id="@+id/like"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    layout="@layout/comment_actions"
    style="@style/LikeStyle" /> <!--here,you are setting a style for the RelativeLayout -->
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: I understood that a couple of hours ago and now I set drawable to these image buttons (like, dislike,etc) in the code though there is still a problem that when I reference a selector, nothing draws on buttons but when reference a png drawable, buttons get that png.

Comment: how do you reference the selector?

Comment: I have a like.xml in drawable folder and reference that this way:
an_ImageButton.setImageBitmap(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(context.getResources(), R.drawable.like));

Comment: how about using   button.setImageResource(resId);

Comment: I would try that, but what if I use imageView instead of imagebutton

Comment: imagebutton is a subclass of imageview, so the same

Comment: It worked, thank you very much.
Do you know why setImageBitmap doesn't work?